# Is it possible to open running background app on in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, nsnotifications, localnotification

open my app from background running on a specific timing..

want to do somthing like this

```
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:NO];
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer*)timer
{

NSLog( @"yes it is running...");
PickUpCallViewController  *call=[[PickUpCallViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PickUpCallViewController" bundle:nil];

navi=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:call];
[[navi navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
window.rootViewController = navi;

[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: This is not possible. As apple's guidelines you cannot open APP without user's permission.

Comment: :( .. any trick... to do this

Comment: Do a WEB SERVICE call and send push notification.

Answer (score 13):

It is not possible to open programmatically app when you application in to background Mode. But using URL-scheme you can open App from browser.

You just need to set URL scheme as following screenshot:-

- First you need to open **project-->Target-->info**

[image]

- After this click on info you found at Bottom like this screenshot:

[image]

- Click on URL Type you got result like following screenshot:

[image]

- click on **(+)** and setting URL-Schemes as following:

[image]

Save and minimized your application by tapping Home button and open your safari browser. and just type **mytestApp://** that you are setting before save as following screenshot:-

[image]

That all process working fine like:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think its possible by using Remote notification(ios7 new background method) without showing uialertview interface.....

Comment: if you have some code.. plz share it .. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As per iOS limitation we can't able to open any app without user interaction. If you need to open any app then you either force the user to do buy sending push notification where user could able to see your notification and can click to view the app.

Also for opening the app from another app or from a link then you can follow the URL schema method like Nitin Gohel explained above.

If you need to fetch a certain data without user interaction then you can use silent push notification which is commonly called as background fetch. You need to enable the push notification in the background  mode and use **application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:** method to handle inside the app. Also we need to make few tweaks in the server side while sending the push notification

```
    aps { content-available: 1 alert: {...} }
```

There is lot more stuff available in net regarding background fetch and you can able to understand how it is working in the [this](http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/) link.