# iOS Detect whether my app is still installed on device

Tags: ios

I am developing for enterprise application and no need to submit to app store.

We need our user to install our app as mandatory. If they delete, we need to track and may advice to install back.

Currently, I am thinking to do like this.

1) Send silent push notification to device and app reply back to server.

2) Run background service daily and post to server back.

Problem is that for push notification, if user deny access, it will not be working. For background service, if user don't accept allow, it won't be working too.

Is there any way to do for that?

Comment: you can use any analytics engine like Google Analytics, http://www.flurry.com etc for the same.

Comment: you can also open install app by setting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632405/is-it-possible-to-open-running-background-app-on-in-objective-c

Comment: it can be a solution to register for push notification, and when you post a notification and APNs Provider API provides you an error message if the device's token is no longer active (`410`); that can be when the app is deleted and is not capable of receiving any more push notification – but that is a kinda implicit way of achieving that; you can read more about that here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/APNsProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1

Comment: If I just open app 1 time and never open again, can flurry detect whether user still have that app ? @Gagan_iOS

Comment: @holex Thanks. I got 410 if user app is deleted. If user device is offline, will I also get 410?

Comment: @NitinGohel I think it is not duplicate question because for that question, it has kind of 2 application. But for me, I only have 1 application.

Comment: yes, flurry tells number of devices uninstall, install, touch in view etc.

Comment: @KhantThuLinn, the `reason` key's values can tell you more information about the actual `status` code, if necessary.

Comment: why not using iOS means for that? use MDM distribution with mandatory app listing